# Django-photologue retrieve images/galleries on angular2 frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-photologue to create a few galleries and attaching them to specific model. On backend side everything works fine.

I have written a model like following:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='news')
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.title)
```

How can I retrieve those galleries/ photos on my Angular2 frontend when I am accessing say *News* model?

I wrote a serializer like following, but looks like it's not the way to do so.

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = News
            fields = '__all__'
```

I have a written a view like following just to see what it returns:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_news(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    galleries = Gallery.objects.all()
    for gallery in galleries:
        print(gallery.sample())
        for photo in gallery.public():
            print(photo.get_absolute_url())
    for anews in news:
        for photo in anews.gallery.public():
            print(photo)
    serializer = NewsSerializer(news, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```